# Isomorphism between class functions and representation ring

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products, characters

Let $R(G)$ be the representation ring of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}_{class}(G)=\{\text{class functions on $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$}\}$. There is injective ring homomorphism $$\chi: R(G) \to \mathbb{C}_{class}(G)$$
maps virtual representations to their virtual characters.

The book that I am reading (Fulton&Harris) states that "our last proposition amounts to the statement that $\chi$ induces an isomorphism $$\chi_{\mathbb{C}}: R(G) \otimes \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}_{class}(G),"$$

where the last proposition is the fact that the character of irreps form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}_{class}(G)$.

I do not understand why their last proposition is equivalent to the mentioned isomorphism. Can you explain why? Furthermore, I have not seen the tensor product of rings. I have only seen the tensor product of modules and that of algebras. So, do the authors consider $R(G)$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra? Is $\chi_{\mathbb{C}}$ isomorphism of algebras?

Comment: The tensor product is over $\mathbb{Z}$. This is just an extension of scalars so we can talk about $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of representations. As an abelian group $R(G)$ is free abelian on the irreducible representations and $R(G) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is just the free vector space on the irreducible representations instead.

Comment: Is it true that, if $V$ is a $K$-vector space and $F$ is an extension of $K$, then $V \otimes F$ is $F$-vector space?

Comment: I assume you mean $V \otimes_K F$. Then yes, and moreover any basis of $V$ as a $K$-vector space remains a basis of $V \otimes_K F$ as an $F$-vector space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars for more details.